# Chrome: Print on multiple printers simultaneously

Tags: google-chrome, printing, scripting, virtual-printer

our company policy forces me to use Chrome and Gmail at work, and I need a solution for the following problem:

Need to send print jobs from Chrome to multiple printers simultaneously, but with different print settings for each individual printer. Basically I need to chain the same document to two printers, but with individual page layout settings for each printer.

```
1st: DIN A4 printer, Checkbox "fit to page" must be set in Chrome's print dialogue. 

2nd: Zebra Label Printer, Checkbox "fit to page" must not be set.
```

1. How would one code a button into Chrome which does exactly that?
2. Alternatively, how would one code a virtual printer which does exactly that? Or in general, how does one chain documents to multiple printers in Windows 7?
3. Can the problem be solved with AutoIt scripts (or similar)?
4. Anyone in here maybe knows a commercial product? Already tried out [Ricoh Print&Share](http://www.printandshare.info), which can chain a doc to many printers, but this tool lacks the fit-to-page options for the individual printer, and only forwards the output it receives from Chrome, without rescaling the pagesize for each printer.

Thanks for reading, appreciate any help on my printer chain issue.

Regards,

Markus

Comment: Welcome to SO. However, as written, your question doesn't fit within the scope of SO. Questions 1 and 2 are too broad (try something, show us what you've tried, and why it doesn't work). Question 3 is off topic because asking for product recommendations are not allowed on SO. Also, your question might (but check with that site!) fit better on Super User, another SE page.

Comment: 4) I just printed an A3 document landscape to Ricoh Print&Share with has a printer channel set to "Paper size: A4" and "Page orientation: portrait".
My A3 landscape document is scaled to my A4 portrait page.

You probably have your settings still set to "automatically" instead of selection a paper size?

Comment: Thanks for your input. Seems I need to reformulate my question. -Can someone provide working code examples on how to build a button/app in Chrome that would solve the problem?